# How to avoid executing entire python script when a function is called without main after importing to another python script

Tags: python

I have a python script which goes like this, which I'm NOT allowed to modify:

```
#file1.py

def add(a, b):
    print(a + b)

add(1, 2)
#no main function whatsoever
```

and I HAVE TO IMPORT `file1.py` in my source code and use the function, I'm not allowed to rewrite the same function on my own.

So, my code goes like this:

```
#my_code.py

import file1
#or
#from file1 import add

def main():     
    file1.add(1, 3)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

which, Obviously results in:

```
3
4
```

Is there any possible way to simply invoke the function and return, without letting that `add(1, 2)` in `file1.py` being invoked ?

I simply need the output on console of the function I invoke in my main function, not the `file1.py` one.

The current make-shift thing I'm doing is:

```
import os
import file1
os.system('cls')

#rest of the code follows
```

It's not very efficient or the brightest idea, but it's enough to get my work done and get my assignment checked.

Comment: *"it's enough to get my work done and get my assignment checked"* - So what's the problem? If it fits the constraints of the assignment, it's a solution, no? Why bother looking for a different solution? Are you aware that [modules **have to be executed** as part of the import process](/a/6523852/4518341)? Does the assignment have any other constraints, like say, can you rename `file1.py` and put something else in its place? Please read [How to ask and answer homework questions](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/4518341). See also [ask] in general.

Comment: @wjandrea. We look beyond our homework to learn.

Comment: @wjandrea The only reason I'm trying to look for a more optimized way is to learn and upgrade myself, I can and will complete the assignment, but the make-shift way, poorly written source file and stupid constrains are a deadly combination which I couldn't handle simultaneously, or I'm still a novice. So, I was seeking some other way which I either overlooked or didn't know yet.

Comment: @Prerit Sorry, rereading my comment, it might sound overly harsh. I didn't want to discourage you learning, just wanted to make sure we're not wasting our time. What I was trying to say was, what you're asking for *in the title* is not possible, and this is maybe an unrealistic situation, so I can think of a lot of other solutions (like, to start: regex, AST, and output redirection), but I don't want to post an answer without knowing all the constraints, or in broader terms, what the *goal* of the assignment is.

Comment: @Mad Totally. What I was trying to get at is that this question is maybe too broad for Stack Overflow. I replied to OP above.

Comment: for output redirection, see [redirect the stdout of an third-party module to /dev/null](/q/56980264/4518341) (ShadowRanger's answer)

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is any better than the `cls` method you have but: overwite `print`, load the module, reset `print`.

```
import builtins

old_print = print
def p(x):
    pass
builtins.print = p
import file1
builtins.print = old_print

def main():     
    file1.add(1, 3)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Thanks, That's actually better than cls in some ways, cls is platform dependent. Also, this method will help me overcome the actual stuff that's going on in the actual function which i have to use.  (But well, If i have such poorly written source which I can't even modify, I shouldn't be thinking about platform independency. )

Answer (score 1):

If you can't  modify a file that executes actions directly without guadring it by checking the `__name__` variable, there is nothing you can do, short of copying that file to another one you can modify, and modify that one.

This process of copying the file, and disabling the function calls can even be automated - but as you can see, it *is* a modification on the source code.

Short of it, maybe (and I said -maybe-) a customization of the import mechanism prior to importing the target file could modify its code prior to execution, by suppressing toplevel calls to locally defined functions, for example, or name mangling the functions and injecting mock functions into the namespace, or a similar mechanism - but that is hard to do and error prone - prefer copying the original file and fixing it instead.

You have to understand that you describe a case in which the original file is essentially hard coded to run the function, and nothing short of changing it, be it manually editing, or programatically changing what the file does, can change that.
And that the doing this: automatically changing what the file does, is just "changing the original file" the same way, just automated, and a task that can be very complicated to automate.

Comment: I do understand that it's basically hardcoded thing, I can't argue with the professor about the code and issues that's why working on a work around.

Comment: Regarding "suppressing toplevel calls", you can use [AST](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html) for that. [Martijn Pieters posted an answer here for a similar situation](/a/48771194/4518341).

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing it is to parse it, pick the function body, compile and call it. The below code demonstrates the idea:

```
# WARNING: for educational purposes only, not to be run in production
import sys
import ast


def inject_from(tree, funcname):
    for element in tree.body:
        if isinstance(element, ast.FunctionDef):
            if funcname == element.name:
                f = ast.unparse(element) # requires >= 3.9
                exec(f)
                return locals()[funcname]
    return None

if __name__ == "__main__":
    filename = sys.argv[1]
    with open(filename) as fd:
        tree = ast.parse(fd.read())
        fname = sys.argv[2]
        function = inject_from(tree, fname)
        if function:
            # we know what we are calling
            print(function(*(int(a) for a in sys.argv[3:])))
        else:
            print(f"{fname} not found in {filename}")
```

The problem with the above code (along with the obvious problem of executing dynamically loaded code) is that it assumes the function doesn't have dependencies. If it does then you might want to approach it from the other side - ast.parse it, exclude everything you don't want to be executed.